# Boot failing and weird workaround

Tags: boot, bios, acer-veriton

After I push the power button, I have to do a little trick in order to boot my old Acer Veriton.

Basically I need to enter into BIOS settings, save and then exit. If I don't do so, I end up with a black screen prompting

```
Reboot and Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press any key
```

This kind of behavior happens only on cold boot (soft reboot works fine), and used to be more sporadic. Now it happens every time I boot my PC and I don't use the workaround described above.

Entering BIOS settings and exiting without saving won't always do the trick.
When I enter BIOS settings I've noticed that it doesn't always detect all of my hard drives, it might be related?

It's not particularly annoying, since I can still use the PC. But it is weird and I would like to understand what's happening here. I suspect that the hard-drive is not automatically detected, but why should it be so? Anyone has any idea? Is there a way to solve this bug?

I'll leave you some technical information, as they appear in BIOS:

```
System Product Name: Veriton M460/S460
MB Product Name: EG31M
System Manufacture Name: ACER
SMBIOS Version: 2.5.0
System BIOS Version: R01-C1
```

Comment: I'd say, flat CMOS battery. Change it & report back.

Comment: @Tetsujin I changed the battery with a new one, issue still present.